# I'm not able to login starbucks with selenium

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, facebook-php-webdriver

I can log in other websites, but starbucks.com seems special. The script was stuck at the login page for ever.

Here is the screenshot after submitted:

[image]

linux+php+chromedriver+facebook-php-webdriver+selenium

`````
    try{
        $driver->get('https://app.starbucks.com/account/signin?ReturnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.starbucks.com%2F');
sleep(60);
        $driver->takeScreenshot("s.png");
        $user=$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id("username"));
        $user->sendKeys("wild****@gmail.com");
sleep(60);
        $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id("password"))->sendKeys("xxxx+")->submit();
sleep(60);
        $driver->wait(60, 1000)->until(
                WebDriverExpectedCondition::titleIs('Starbucks Coffee Company')
        );
        $cookies = $driver->manage()->getCookies();
        print_r($cookies);````

I got a few warnings and a severe from console log, what do those mean?

 [6]=>
  array(3) {
    ["level"]=>
    string(7) "WARNING"
    ["message"]=>
    string(190) "https://jssdkcdns.mparticle.com/js/v2/2689bb1f07a4544aa30798862ab1df07/mparticle.js 28:61854 "The corresponding attribute value of nonInteraction must be a string, number, boolean, or null.""
    ["timestamp"]=>
    int(1562331865383)
  }
  [7]=>
  array(3) {
    ["level"]=>
    string(6) "SEVERE"
    ["message"]=>
    string(157) "https://assets.web.starbucksassets.com/weblx/static/signIn.7ee7f5476580837359aa.chunk.js 0:21324 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined"
    ["timestamp"]=>
    int(1562331865383)
  }
`````

Comment: Look what is happening in the console in DevTools, maybe some problem with the webpage. Also, you can try to run your code on firefox, maybe here a page will not stuck and you can check if there are no problems with your code

Comment: Thank you cheparsky, I have updated the question with new console log

Comment: You get warning in console warning because there are some errors in "mparticle.js 28:61854". You get severe because there is some error between application and server, you have no influence on it. You can try again run your test and see if you still have "severe" problem. Also, you can eventually try your test on another browser and/or language.